# save_post not triggered when a post is updated

Tags: actions, save-post

I'm encountering something weird.

I made a function on functions.php that I want to trigger when a post is saved or updated.

```
function gh_set_inner_project_order($post_id){

  $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_id );

  var_dump($parent_id);
  if($parent_id == 4){
    $page_projects = gh_get_inner_project_order($post_id);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($page_projects as $project_id) {
      update_field('inner_order', $i, $project_id);
      $i++;
    }
  }

}
```

And then, simply :

```
add_action('save_post', 'gh_set_inner_project_order');
```

On my localhost, it works fine. The function is triggeredwhen I save a post or when I update it, it logs the $parent_id.

**But on the distant server, it only works when I create a new post / page. I really can't figure out why.**

Any idea?

EDIT:

Just to be sure, I modified my function so it's really minimal now:

```
function gh_set_inner_project_order(){


  var_dump('---------- gh_set_inner_project_order ---------');


}
```

But still, it doesn't work when I update a post on the distant server (no issue on my localhost).

Comment: On local server, it returns the expected ID when I publish a post or when I update it, but on distant server, it only works when I create a new post, not on update.

Comment: Actually, it does! So it's triggered, but the var_dump() wasn't displayed. Is it about var_dump() and distant server PHP conf (I'm not expert in that kind of stuff)?

Comment: A `var_dump()` in `save_post` action doesn't display any information on the screen. If you need to debug `save_post` action, you can follow [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress). But you already know it is triggered, the only problem I see in your code is the hardcoded `$parent_id == 4`; it is very probably that the parent id is not always 4.

Comment: @cybmeta I think that's not true! It displays the output but may be hidden behind admin bar!

Comment: @Sumit This is what I was missing, I assumed that var_dump() had a constant behavior on all servers. Thanks.

Comment: @Sumit, you are wrong. Test yourself. You can not display information on screen using `var_dump()` in `save_post` action. It is not a server issue.

Comment: Well, another question: why the var_dump() was working as expected when I created a post, but not when I updated it ? This is what made me going nuts.

Comment: Not for me and not for a lot of people. That is why [questions like one this exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress).

Comment: Oh, yes, `var_dump` displays information when creating a "new" post. Not anymore. That is just the way `save_post` action is triggered. Follow what I've commentd in the answer.

Comment: Okay sorry @cybmeta I just completely forgot about redirection after saving post. I was testing suing `var_dump('called'); die;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `var_dump()` in `save_post` action doesn't display any information on the screen. Well, it does only when you are on "Add new" screen. This is due the different sequence of actions that follow when creating a new post or when editing it.

When you click on "publish" or "update" button, there is a request, the post is saved, `save_post` action is triggered and then you are redirected to the edit screen.

The redirection implies a new request and this new request doesn't trigger the `save_post` action, so you can not see any information printed just becasue that action is NOT triggered to generate the screen you are seeing.

If you need to debug `save_post` action, you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress) (it needs [WP_DEBUG on](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and stores the information in the error log file in your server, see [`error_log()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php)):

```
if(!function_exists('log_it')){
 function log_it( $message ) {
   if( WP_DEBUG === true ){
     if( is_array( $message ) || is_object( $message ) ) {
       error_log( print_r( $message, true ) );
     } else {
       error_log( $message );
     }
   }
 }
}
```

And then, in the `save_post`  callback:

```
add_action('save_post', 'gh_set_inner_project_order');
function gh_set_inner_project_order() {
    log_it( $parent_id );
    // .... 
}
```

Remember that you can pass a custom error log file to `error_log()` function if you want to log the information in a different file from server log. See [`error_log()` docs](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php) for more information. For example:

```
error_log( $var_to_log, 3 , __DIR__ . "/my-log.txt" );
```

Comment: `$parent_id == 4` is made on purpose : I want to check if the current post is a child a of specific page.

Comment: If that value, 4, is correct and the action is triggered, what is your problem then? I don't get you. Are you sure the parent ID is 4 in local and remote server?

Comment: Read the question: I didn't know that the action was triggered, as there was no var_dump() on distant server when I was updating a post. Note that when I was creating a post on the distant server, I did see the var_dump() value.

Comment: That is why, as I said, you can not use `var_dump()` to display information on `save_post` action. Follow the instructions in the linked question if you need to debug `save_post` action (answer updated to include the sample code for debuggin `save_post`).

Comment: Answer updated again.

Comment: I tested your debug function, copying and pasting you code, but it doesn't provides a better log to me: it just shows no log at all (on update and post creation).

Comment: The information is written in the log file in your sever.

Comment: And note also that the function I posted need [WP_DEBUG on](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG), which is appropiate as you are debugging.

Comment: Mmm ok, that sounds actually a better way to debug this kind of actions, thanks.

Comment: I've added a little more information about the need of WP_DEBUG and `error_log()` function. If this post answers your question, please consider mark it as accepted answer so other users can find the answer quickly.

Comment: +1 for sharing that debugging style. But I suggest that this line may include a redirection mystery _This is due the different sequence of actions that follow when creating a new post or when editing it._ because now people like me may ask why it works with a `die;` :D

Comment: Is it possible to modify the log_it function to have something like `if( WP_DEBUG_LOG == true ){`? Right now, it's like error_log() will only perform if WP_DEBUG is true (which makes `WP_DEBUG == true` kinda useless.

Comment: @Sumit I added a explanation of the redirection, maybe you read the answer before I did it.

Comment: @enguerranws I don't understand what you mean with `WP_DEBUG == true` being useless. In my opinion, debug information is useful if we are in a debugging environment, which makes `WP_DEBUG == true` very useful. `WP_DEBUG_LOG == true` it also very useful, use whatever is best for you. Just note the `WP_DEBUG_LOG` makes WordPress to generate a debug file with [all PHP errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), including notices and warnings.

Comment: I don't say it's useless, I say that in your code `if(WP_DEBUG == true)` doesn't seem to be useful, as long as WP_DEBUG must be set to true in order to make error_log() works in Wordpress.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, but you are wrong. `error_log()` works even if `WP_DEBUG` is `false`.